# Amazon S3 javascript and css files 403

Tags: javascript, css, amazon-s3

I have some javascript and css files linked in head tag of my page. All the page content (index.html page and javascript and css files) is located in a bucket. When I launch index.html page,  I get 403 errors on all those javascript and css files:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

This must be some setting on amazon S3 which prevent these files from accessing?

Can you help me resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to check if your files are configured as public:**

[image]

**Or grant permissions using a Bucket policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: My account has all permissions: https://snag.gy/f39Ytg.jpg    public has this:  https://snag.gy/qLzoKx.jpg  but I still get same error.

Comment: @Toniq these images you’ve shared are related to the bucket rather than file permissions.

Comment: I see now. Is there a way to set this permission for all files in one go or similar? because its giving me 403 for every type of file now, and adjusting for each file is painful.

Comment: Changed all bucket and file permissions...still doesn't work for me.